# ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE DIVISION

Tags: assembly

For DIV, the dividend is 5 and the divisor is FFFEh = 65534; 5 divided
by 65534 yields a quotient of O and a remainder of 5.
For IDIV, the dividend is 5 and the divisor is FFFEh = -2; 5 divided
by -2 gives a quotient of -2 and a remainder of 1.

FFFEh = -2  ?

Comment: Yes, learn about 2's complement.

Comment: @MarkusLaire: Thanks for finding that dup target, that answers this question nicely.